# Filter multicast on a LAN

Tags: firewalls

In my dd-wrt firewall, I see the option:

```
filter multicast
```

I searched a lot about filtering multicast, but I could not find a comprehensive reply about this. Should I filter multicast on my LAN?

Comment: It's going to depend on whether or not your LAN has services that use multicast. Firstly, do you know what multicast is? If we knew that, we could provide a more precise answer.